# Delete inline width and height from table row

Tags: php, regex

I need a PHP regex (preg_replace) that deletes the width and height of an inline style element, and that leaves everything else in tact. So this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; min-width: 30px; padding-right: 10px; height: 12px; width: 15px;" valign="top"></td>
```

should become this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; min-width: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" valign="top"></td>
```

The regex must also detect that it's inside a  tag because it's part of a larger HTML string with tags that must remain their width and height style elements.

Comment: Try this regex : https://regex101.com/r/jf50vR/1

Comment: A bit wrong. This regex also affect min-width :(

Comment: In this case, that's a good thing.

Comment: Why is regex being used on HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```html
<?php
$tag = '<td style="vertical-align: top; min-width: 30px; padding-right: 10px; height: 12px; width: 15px;" valign="top"></td>';
echo preg_replace('/(\"|\s|;)(width:|height:).*?(;|")/', '', $tag);
?>
```

Comment: Almost there. It must detect that it's inside a <TD> tag. The $tag variable contains other HTML with inline styles that must be left alone.